# Ability to enforce a Static Class methods' follow the signature of a Delegate

Tags: c#

I have some delegates:

```
public class StringDelegates
{
    public delegate string StringMethod(object container);
}

public class IntegerDelegates
{
    public delegate int IntegerMethod(object container);
}

public class DoubleDelegates
{
    public delegate double DoubleMethod(object container);
}
```

and I have some static classes that contain methods that follow this delegate signature:

```
public static class StringGenerators
{
    public static string FirstName(object container)
    {
        return Name.GetFirstName((string)container);
    }

    public static string LastName(object container)
    {
        return Name.GetLastName();
    }
}

public static class IntegerGenerators
{
    public static int Range(object container)
    {
        string[] args = (string[])container;
        int min = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        int max = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
        return RandomGenerator.GetRandomInt(min, max);
    }
}
```

My question: Is there any way to enforce these classes implement methods that adhere to the delegate signature?

Comment: At compile-time? Nope. You can easily write unit tests though.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's too bad there's not a way at compile-time. I suppose the unit test idea will suffice, do you perhaps have any links/examples I can take a look at? Feel free to submit as an answer and I can accept it

Comment: @TalenKylon If `StringGenerators` etc. weren't static classes, you could write interfaces. Then maybe give each one a singleton instance. E.g. `StringGenerators` would have `private static StringGenerators _instance = new StringGenerators(); public static StringGenerators Instance { get { return _instance; } }` Make the constructors private. Far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. I'm not recommending this, but it's a literal answer to your question:

```
public static class StringGenerators
{
    public static StringDelegates.StringMethod FirstName = container => 
        Name.GetFirstName((string) container);
}
```

Comment: It's not really a literal answer to the question: 1) there are now *no* methods in the class, just a public field. 2) it doesn't prevent any other methods being introduced in the class that don't follow the pattern.

Comment: It's as close as it's going to get.

Comment: Possibly - but I think an answer of just "Nope" is more accurate.